# Image in User control not display while executing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created a user control; it contains an image control and placed that image in xaml code. The image properly displayed in User control. This was added to Window. But Image in user control is not displayed when executing the application.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="PsyboInventory.Tiles.EmployeeTile.DepartmentTile"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          Opacity="1" Height="209" Width="220" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="TileSurfaceRct" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0.14"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="TileSurfaceRct" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.14"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave1}" x:Name="OnMouseLeave1_BeginStoryboard"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="TileBgrndRct" Fill="{DynamicResource TileBgrndRctFill}" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="10,179,141,10" x:Name="TileTxtBlck" FontSize="12" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" Text="Department" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="TileSurfaceRct" Fill="#FF000000" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FFFBFBFB" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Image Height="174" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="/PsyboInventory;component/img/department.png"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This user control added to Window dynamically.

```
        DepartmentTile depart = new DepartmentTile();
        StackPanel panel1 = new StackPanel();
        panel1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0);
        panel1.Children.Add(depart);
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Width = Double.NaN;
        grid.Height = Double.NaN;
        grid.Children.Add(panel1);
        MetroStackPanel.Children.Add(grid);
```

While executing; their is no error.but no image displaying in UserControl

```
      <Window x:Class="PsyboInventory.start"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="start" Height="526" Width="832" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="{x:Null}" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Initialized="Window_Initialized" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Seting Image for back Button-->
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonImageBack" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" ImageSource="/PsyboInventory;component/img/exit.png"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BackImg">
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource ButtonImageBack}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            <!-- If we don't tell the background to change on hover, it will remain the same -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!-- Seting Image for logout Button-->
    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonImageLog" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" ImageSource="/PsyboInventory;component/img/save.png"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LogImg">
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource ButtonImageLog}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonImageQuit" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" ImageSource="/PsyboInventory;component/img/edit.png"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="QuitImg">
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource ButtonImageQuit}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ImageBrush x:Key="ButtonImageHome" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" ImageSource="/PsyboInventory;component/img/delete.png"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="HomeImg">
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource ButtonImageHome}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="Close">
                            <Canvas Width="15.4167" Height="15.5001">
                                <Path x:Name="Rect1" Width="15.4167" Height="15.5001" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#00000000" Data="F1 M 2,0L 13.4167,0C 14.5212,0 15.4167,0.895447 15.4167,2L 15.4167,13.5001C 15.4167,14.6046 14.5212,15.5001 13.4167,15.5001L 2,15.5001C 0.895447,15.5001 0,14.6046 0,13.5001L 0,2C 0,0.895447 0.895447,0 2,0 Z "/>
                                <Path x:Name="X1" Width="15.001" Height="15.001" Canvas.Left="0.209" Canvas.Top="0.235" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 14.7216,0.723328C 15.3725,1.37421 15.3725,2.4295 14.7216,3.08038L 10.0667,7.73535L 14.7218,12.3905C 15.3727,13.0414 15.3726,14.0966 14.7217,14.7475C 14.0709,15.3984 13.0156,15.3984 12.3647,14.7475L 7.70959,10.0924L 3.05438,14.7476C 2.4035,15.3985 1.34827,15.3985 0.697388,14.7476C 0.0465088,14.0967 0.0465088,13.0414 0.697388,12.3906L 5.3526,7.73541L 0.697449,3.08026C 0.0465698,2.42938 0.0465698,1.37415 0.697449,0.723267C 1.34833,0.0723877 2.40363,0.0723877 3.0545,0.723267L 7.70966,5.37836L 12.3646,0.723328C 13.0155,0.0724487 14.0707,0.0724487 14.7216,0.723328 Z "/>
                                <Path x:Name="X2" Width="13.6364" Height="13.6351" Canvas.Left="0.891403" Canvas.Top="0.91861" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFD7D7D7" Data="F1 M 1.19855,1.2243C 1.60614,0.816711 2.26715,0.816711 2.67474,1.2243L 7.70966,6.25922L 12.7444,1.22443C 13.152,0.816711 13.813,0.816711 14.2207,1.22437C 14.6284,1.63202 14.6284,2.29303 14.2206,2.70062L 9.18585,7.73541L 14.222,12.7716C 14.6297,13.1793 14.6297,13.8402 14.222,14.2479C 13.8143,14.6556 13.1535,14.6556 12.7458,14.2479L 7.70966,9.21173L 2.67346,14.2479C 2.26575,14.6556 1.6048,14.6556 1.19714,14.2479C 0.78949,13.8403 0.78949,13.1793 1.19714,12.7716L 6.23334,7.73541L 1.19855,2.70062C 0.790894,2.29297 0.790833,1.63202 1.19855,1.2243 Z "/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="X2" Value="#FF67C8FF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MinimizeButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="Minimize">
                            <Canvas Width="15.4166" Height="15.5">
                                <Path x:Name="Rect" Width="15.4166" Height="15.5" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#00C80000" Data="F1 M 2,0L 13.4166,0C 14.5212,0 15.4166,0.895386 15.4166,2L 15.4166,13.5C 15.4166,14.6046 14.5212,15.5 13.4166,15.5L 2,15.5C 0.895386,15.5 0,14.6046 0,13.5L 0,2C 0,0.895386 0.895386,0 2,0 Z "/>
                                <Path x:Name="Path" Width="15" Height="3.29211" Canvas.Left="0.203247" Canvas.Top="12.0621" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 1.84924,12.0621L 13.5572,12.0621C 14.4663,12.0621 15.2032,12.7991 15.2032,13.7082L 15.2032,13.7082C 15.2032,14.6173 14.4663,15.3542 13.5572,15.3542L 1.84924,15.3542C 0.940186,15.3542 0.203247,14.6173 0.203247,13.7082L 0.203247,13.7082C 0.203247,12.7991 0.940186,12.0621 1.84924,12.0621 Z "/>
                                <Path x:Name="Path_0" Width="13.6262" Height="2.20911" Canvas.Left="0.890076" Canvas.Top="12.6036" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFCBCBCB" Data="F1 M 1.99463,12.6036L 13.4117,12.6036C 14.0218,12.6036 14.5162,13.0981 14.5162,13.7082L 14.5162,13.7082C 14.5162,14.3182 14.0218,14.8127 13.4117,14.8127L 1.99463,14.8127C 1.38458,14.8127 0.890076,14.3182 0.890076,13.7082L 0.890076,13.7082C 0.890076,13.0981 1.38458,12.6036 1.99463,12.6036 Z "/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Path_0" Value="#FF67C8FF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExtrasGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="-35"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ExtrasGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-35"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>



    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="SidesGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="-35"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="SidesGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-35"/>
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Style x:Key="SkinButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FFB50000" Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="rectangle"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FFD10000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="GreenButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF04822A" Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="rectangle"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF05A234"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BlueButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF04457C" Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="rectangle"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF035396"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PurpleButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#FF67037A" Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="rectangle"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF85029E"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="SettingsButtonStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateCogReverse">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="179.06"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="90"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="RotateCog">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="path" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="90"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="179.06"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#FF000000"/>
                        <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{x:Null}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.500000004069009,0.5" Data="M11.2495,6.0420003 C8.3734743,6.0420003 6.0420003,8.3737047 6.0420003,11.25 6.0420003,14.126296 8.3734766,16.458 11.2495,16.458 14.125523,16.458 16.457001,14.126297 16.457001,11.25 16.457001,8.3737034 14.125525,6.0420003 11.2495,6.0420003 z M9.4165001,0 L13.0835,0 13.0835,3.2868118 14.492886,3.5713878 15.593504,4.3135347 17.90847,1.9985683 20.501431,4.5915289 18.186081,6.9068799 18.927191,8.0062256 19.211878,9.4165001 22.5,9.4165001 22.5,13.0835 19.211878,13.0835 18.927191,14.493774 18.186081,15.59312 20.501431,17.90847 17.90847,20.501432 15.593504,18.186464 14.492886,18.928612 13.0835,19.213188 13.0835,22.5 9.4165001,22.5 9.4165001,19.21339 8.006115,18.928612&#xa;6.9060936,18.186867 4.5915289,20.501432 1.9985685,17.90847 4.3133221,15.593717 3.5718093,14.493774 3.2871222,13.0835 0,13.0835 0,9.4165001 3.2871222,9.4165001 3.5718093,8.0062256 4.3133221,6.9062824 1.9985685,4.5915289 4.5915289,1.9985683 6.9060926,4.3131323 8.006115,3.5713878 9.4165001,3.2866099 z" x:Name="path">
                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleX="0" AngleY="0"/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                        </Path>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateCogReverse}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RotateCog}" x:Name="RotateCog_BeginStoryboard"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SettingsButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF1E8E88" Stroke="#FF7C7C7C" x:Name="rectangle"/>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="#FF12A59D"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="ExtrasCanvas">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave" SourceName="ExtrasCanvas">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave1}" x:Name="OnMouseLeave1_BeginStoryboard"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Rectangle x:Name="MainBgrndRct" Fill="{DynamicResource MainBgrndRctFill}" Stroke="{DynamicResource MainBgrndRctStroke}"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-44,-49" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="281" Height="225" Visibility="Visible">
        <Ellipse Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#22FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="79,23,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#19FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,35,0,76" Width="114"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#1EFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="86,7,131,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="64"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Margin="156,-18,415,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="234" Visibility="Visible">
        <Ellipse Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="#25FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="-49,-72,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Height="120"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="#24FFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="-21,-25,94,71" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

        </Ellipse>
        <Ellipse Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="#1FFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="100,82,61,52"/>
        <Ellipse Fill="{x:Null}" Stroke="#1EFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="3" Margin="0,48,60,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="56" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>

    <Canvas Margin="10,126,10,33" x:Name="MainCanvas" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#00000000">
        <StackPanel  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Canvas.Left="45" Canvas.Top="0" x:Name="MetroStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#00000000" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource CloseButtonStyle}" Width="11.195" Content="Button" x:Name="CloseButton" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.583,7.468,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="12.77" Click="CloseButton_Click"/>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource MinimizeButtonStyle}" Width="12.402" Content="Button" x:Name="MinimizeButton" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,4.733,24.606,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="13.537"/>




</Grid>
```

Comment: Where is TileBgrndRctFill defined?

Comment: That not a problem.After removing it. same problem exist

Comment: The usercontrol is working fine for me even when executed. Can you post your Window.xaml code?

Comment: If the question is about `/PsyboInventory;component/img/department.png`, then make sure that the Build Action of the file `department.png` is set to **Resource**.

Comment: Not set.... how to set department.png into Resource

Comment: After adding images to Resource. The images displayed and properly working. Thank you for your god Advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws a Xamlparse Exception at runtime. That is not related to the usercontrol added dynamically. It is because of the SourceNames that your storyboard and Event Triggers are targetting to. 'ExtraGrids' , 'ExtraCanvas' does not exist in the window.xaml code. Hence replaceing it with correct sourceNames will run your code perfectly fine.
Just comment out code inside  and  and you will know the difference.

This is a reference link for the exception occured. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f803f28-dfda-4be5-9e8d-f7d82db95961/c-wpf-systemwindowsmarkupxamlparseexception?forum=wpf

Comment: 'ExtraGrids' , 'ExtraCanvas' are already added in My code. Stackoverflow only accept 30000 character code only.But my code has more than it. Thus I remove this section from stackoverflow.

Comment: @ShahidNeermunda In that case the code just runs fine for me.One thing you can check with is the build action. Just rightclick on the image in solution explorer and check its properties. Build Action should be set to "Resource" and Copy to Output Directory option should have "Copy Always" selected from dropdown